# "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module" when there are multiple "ng-app" directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS , and while I was experimenting I met this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify th......0)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Controller( $scope, $location ){
           //
        }

        function Controller2( $scope, $location ){
           //
        }
    </script>
    <title>Angular JS Application</title>
</head>
    <body >
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller='Controller' >
                <h1>App1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-app="myApp2">
            <div ng-controller='Controller2' >
                <h1>App2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody explain,what is the problem?

Comment: _Only one_ `ngApp` _directive can be used per HTML Document_.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak It is not true. While I am trying to register controllers by `angular.module('',[]).controller` method, works fine, but when controllers are global , I am getting that error.

Comment: can you post your js file?

Comment: @wickY26 I have posted all the code.

Comment: where is your JS file where you define module myApp?

Comment: @SlavenTomac There is no JS file, besides "angular.js" from the Google's CDN

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, is correct. You can only *auto bootstrap* one App. See [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no module to bind. just add following code to your js and you should be fine

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
var myModule2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
```

**UPDATE**

You can only use on ng-app per html which is auto bootstrap your application for you, but you can run more than one app per page by manually bootstrap your app module...

here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4jNPtF783zR126MB0JM?p=preview) example to show both manually and auto module bootstraping...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is usefull.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your `app` like;

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

and

```
var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

without having this module defined in one of your JS file. e.g.

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/FDXT7bU1akthSflYtCe5?p=preview) your code, please have a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Controller( $scope, $location ){
            alert("hello me 1");
        }

        function Controller2( $scope, $location ){
           alert("hello me 2");
        }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app>
        <div >
            <div ng-controller='Controller' >
                <h1>App1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div ng-controller='Controller2' >
                <h1>App2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**NOTE**

From next time, Please don't use multiple ng-app in single html. if you need to use it, then you can inject one module into the other and then use it.

Comment: If you answer a question, please put the relevant details in the answer. Simply posting a link to an off site resource is not a valid answer.

Comment: This is totally wrong answer. I am interested in case, when I have multiple "ng-app"s with multiple controllers.